# Go client for Hadoop Streaming

Tags: hadoop, go, hadoop-streaming

Is there a well known client for the Go programming language that supports Hadoop Streaming?  I have searched around and was unable to find anything of value.

Answer (score 3):

You could run your Hadoop streaming jobs directly on Go, I've heard of people doing it and here is an example [taken from a blog](http://go-wise.blogspot.com/2011/09/go-on-hadoop.html) that does Wordcount in Go. Here is the mapper:

```
package main

import (
        "bufio"
        "fmt"
        "os"
        "regexp"
)

func main() {
        /* Word regular experssion. */
        re, _ := regexp.Compile("[a-zA-Z0-9]+")
        reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)

        for {
                line, _, err := reader.ReadLine()
                if err != nil {
                        if err != os.EOF {
                                fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "error: can't read - %s\n", err.String())
                        }
                        break
                }
                matches := re.FindAll(line, -1)
                for _, word := range(matches) {
                        fmt.Printf("%s\t1\n", word)
                }
        }
}
```

And here is the reducer:

```
package main

import (
        "bufio"
        "bytes"
        "fmt"
        "os"
        "strconv"
)

func main() {
        counts := make(map[string]uint)
        reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)

        for {
                line, _, err := reader.ReadLine()
                if err != nil {
                        if err != os.EOF {
                                fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "error: can't read - %s\n", err)
                        }
                        break
                }
                i := bytes.IndexByte(line, '\t')
                if i == -1 {
                        fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, "error: can't find tab")
                        continue
                }
                word := string(line[0:i])
                count, err := strconv.Atoui(string(line[i+1:]))
                if err != nil {
                        fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, "error: bad number - %s\n", err)
                        continue
                }

                counts[word] = counts[word] + count
        }

        /* Output aggregated counts. */
        for word, count := range(counts) {
                fmt.Printf("%s\t%d\n", word, count)
        }
}
```

Alternatively, you could also use [dmrgo](https://github.com/dgryski/dmrgo) to make it easier to write your streaming jobs. They have a wordcount example available [here](https://github.com/dgryski/dmrgo/blob/master/examples/wordcount.go).

I saw another library called [gomrjob](https://github.com/jehiah/gomrjob) but it doesn't look very well maintained and very alpha, but you could give it a try if you feel adventurous :)

Comment: Interesting.  I will dig into those links this evening.